# Linux Kernel syscall compile error

Tags: c, linux, kernel, system-calls

I am doing some homework for my operating systems class and I am getting an error on compile but I can't find much info on it.  Here is the code in question (most of it).

```
pgd_t *pgd;
pud_t *pud;
pmd_t *pmd;
pte_t *ptep, pte;

pgd = pgd_offset(mm, address);
pud = pud_offset(pgd, address);
pmd = pmd_offset(pud, address);
ptep = pte_offset_map(pmd, address);
pte = *ptep;
```

My errors are:

- implicit declaration of function 'in_nmi'
- implicit declaration of function 'in_irq'

The line reference is to the second to last line:

```
ptep = pte_offset_map(pmd, address);
```

My assignment is to get the page descriptor given a virtual memory address in Linux.  Am I missing a specific #include?  Also, if what I am doing won't work, can you explain why?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you compile kernel or some module? It can be missed header, yes.

Comment: Compiling kernel.  Should I be using pte_offset_kernel instead of pte_offset_map??

Comment: IIRC, try `#include <asm/pgtable.h>`: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/include/asm/pgtable.h

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was actually supposed to use the pte_offset_kernel instead of pte_offset_map.  I don't know what the difference in the two is, but that little change fixed it and it now compiles.  Thanks again.